# Change colors of \mobile, \address and \title in Modern Cv

Tags: moderncv

**EDIT :** How could I put in bold what is before `\email` ? Something like `\email{\textbf{bla bla}}` doesn't work.

When using `moderncv` to create my CV, I type the following commands :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{nav}{rgb}{0.22,0.45,0.70}% light blue
\usepackage[inner=2.2cm,outer=2.2cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

    \firstname{Name}
    \familyname{\textsc{Name}}
    \title{Name}      
    \address{Name}{Name}  
    \mobile{045454}              
    \email{aaa@aaa.fr}   

    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \end{document}
```

I would like anyhting there in this "nav" color, `\mobile` and `\address` symbols included.

Comment: Yes, indeed I didn't find that post. Futhermore, I would like to put in bold the text after \email but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks it is what I did but I don't really understand the code. I would like the \email to be in bold that's all. In the mentionned thread something is done to put in bold 2 specifical adress

Comment: Try this `\renewcommand*{\emaillink}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\textbf{\href{mailto:#2}{#2}}}%
    {\textbf{\href{mailto:#2}{#1}}}}` P.S. spaces are new lines.

Comment: @Guest In these cases, instead of editing the question, you should ask a new question, since what you've asked in the edit is completely different than the original post!