# Reduce the space between \email symbol and the mail in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

Yesterday I asked several questions such as changing the color of specific headings. The answers are here: [Change colors of \mobile, \address and \title in Modern Cv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131911/change-colors-of-mobile-address-and-title-in-modern-cv)

The other problem I didn't manage to solve was that I wanted to put in bold the mail. The following command does it:

```
\renewcommand*{\emaillink}[2][]{
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
{\textbf{\href{mailto:#2}{#2}}}
{\textbf{\href{mailto:#2}{#1}}}}
```

But I would like to reduce the space between `\email` symbol and the mail. Something like `\email{hspace{-0.2cm} aaa@aaa.com}` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email symbol is put there by the command `\emailsymbol`. The definition of this depends on the icon theme used. For your example it uses symbols from `marvosym`, and the definition of `\emailsymbol` (and others) are found in the file `moderncviconsmarvosym.sty`. There you'll find

```
 \renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}{\marvosymbol{66~}}
```

Which adds a (non breakable) inter word space between the symbol and the email address. Add e.g.

```
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}{\marvosymbol{66}}
```

to your preamble to remove this space, which places the symbol closer to the address. You could also add some negative space here to move it even closer, e.g.

```
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}{\marvosymbol{66}\hspace{-.1cm}}
```

Comment: Many thanks. It is exactly what I expected.